# Specify Azure SQL server edition in EF Core without breaking local development

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework Core introduced the methods [HasServiceTier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlservermodelbuilderextensions.hasservicetier?view=efcore-3.1) and [HasPerformanceLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlservermodelbuilderextensions.hasperformancelevel?view=efcore-3.1) to change the edition of an Azure SQL server. You can use them in [OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.HasServiceTier("Basic");
    modelBuilder.HasPerformanceLevel("Basic");
}
```

If you use Add-Migration [Add-Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs#create-a-migration) you get a migration like this:

```
public partial class ChangedDatabaseServiceTierToBasic : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
            .Annotation("SqlServer:EditionOptions", "EDITION = 'Basic', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'Basic'");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
            .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:EditionOptions", "EDITION = 'Basic', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'Basic'");
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine but when I try to apply this migration to a local non-Azure DB for development purposes I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20200413102908_ChangedDatabaseServiceTierToBasic'.
Applying migration '20200413102908_ChangedDatabaseServiceTierToBasic'.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      BEGIN
      DECLARE @db_name NVARCHAR(MAX) = DB_NAME();
      EXEC(N'ALTER DATABASE ' + @db_name + ' MODIFY ( 
      EDITION = ''Basic'', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ''Basic'' );');
      END
Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
BEGIN
DECLARE @db_name NVARCHAR(MAX) = DB_NAME();
EXEC(N'ALTER DATABASE ' + @db_name + ' MODIFY ( 
EDITION = ''Basic'', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ''Basic'' );');
END
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '.'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:d9f92b81-9916-48ee-9686-6d0f567ab86f
Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

I assume the commands are not valid for non-Azure DBs. So the question is: How can I prevent these commands to be executed on non-Azure DBs?

Comment: How are your migrations run?  If in code, you can switch on ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @PatrickGoode that would only allow me to disable migrations for the local db entirely, right? I want all migrations to run except this one. One solution would be to make the content of the migration dependent on a config-variable. I just wondered if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Rather than wasting bounties, you should really post it to EF Core [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues) because it is their bug/issue - [source](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Migrations/SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.cs#L914). As you can see, there are [conditional blocks](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Migrations/SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.cs#L944) for other things, but not for this one. Of course you can replace their class with custom, but you have to copy/paste/modify the whole method.

Comment: I just saw that you already did that - [#20682](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20682). Good luck.

Comment: @IvanStoev that's some interesting insight in the source code. Thanks for digging it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EF Core team is now aware of the issue and added it to their backlog:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20682

Meanwhile the officially recommended workaround looks like this:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"IF SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 5
EXEC(N'ALTER DATABASE [ThreeOne.SomeDbContext] MODIFY (EDITION = ''Basic'',  SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ''Basic'' );');
");
```

I modified it to work without knowing the current database name:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql
(
@"declare @dbname varchar(100)
set @dbname=quotename(db_name())
IF SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 5
EXEC(N'ALTER DATABASE '+@dbname+' MODIFY (EDITION = ''Basic'', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ''Basic'' );');"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course `EDITION` and `SERVICE_OBJECTIVE` are not supported for non Azure SQL Database.

You need to run your commands only for Azure database. For other types of SQL server you need to miss execution of your code.

I suggest to detect [SQL Server Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) before running your code.

For this purpose you can add extension method:

```
public static class DatabaseFacadeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsSqlAzure(this DatabaseFacade database)
    {
        var parameter = new SqlParameter("edition", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        {
            Size = 128,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        };

        database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT @edition = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS NVARCHAR)", parameter);

        var edition = parameter.Value.ToString();

        return edition.Equals("SQL Azure", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

And inside your `OnModelCreating` method you can use next code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    if (Database.IsSqlAzure())
    {
        modelBuilder.HasServiceTier("Basic");
        modelBuilder.HasPerformanceLevel("Basic");
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is gonna work. The code that causes issues is located in the migration not in OnModelCreating. I considered using something like that in the migration itself but that seems a bit wonky, which is why I opened this question.

Answer (score 0):

This feels very wrong but it works:

```
public partial class ChangedDatabaseServiceTierToBasic : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        if (IsHostedInAzure())
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
                .Annotation("SqlServer:EditionOptions", "EDITION = 'Basic', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'Basic'");
        }
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        if (IsHostedInAzure())
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
                .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:EditionOptions", "EDITION = 'Basic', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'Basic'");
        }
    }

    private static bool IsHostedInAzure()
    {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        var isHostedInAzureConfig = config["DatabaseSettings:IsHostedInAzure"];
        var setEdition = bool.TryParse(isHostedInAzureConfig, out var isHostedInAzure) && isHostedInAzure;
        return setEdition;
    }
}
```